# Webview in standard android browser doesn't open files

Tags: android, webview

When I try upload files opening via standard Android browser, I can't do it. I read in internet, that this trouble of webview.

My system is 4.2.

Is there way to solve this trouble, maybe install any patch?  Or maybe in another version of android there is no this problem and the easy way is updating to new system. How to make webview to work forcibly?

Please don't recommend to use any another browser, I need standard.

Comment: Please don't use backticks (`\``) for emphasis. They should only be used for inline code, file names, etc.

Comment: Ok,Chris. This stylistic remark. But what about my problem do you think?

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, so unfortunately I can't comment on your problem. Good luck!